# correct way to display 3 dimensional array with key and value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 3 dimensional array defined like:

```
$seccc  =  array(   
                                array( 
                                        "Href"      => base_url().'capture/',   
                                        "Icono"     => base_url().'assets/images/icon_home.png', 
                                        "Texto"     => 'Captura',
                                        "Submenu"   => array(1,2,3)
                                    ),
                                array( 
                                        "Href"      => base_url().'seg/',   
                                        "Icono"     => base_url().'assets/images/icon_tra.png', 
                                        "Texto"     => 'Seg',
                                        "Submenu"   => array('ALFA','OMEGAL','DELTA')
                                    ),
                                array( 
                                        "Href"      => base_url().'usr/',   
                                        "Icono"     => base_url().'assets/images/icon_users.png', 
                                        "Texto"     => 'Users',
                                        "Submenu"   => ''
                                    ),  
                                array( 
                                        "Href"      => base_url().'clients/',   
                                        "Icono"     => base_url().'assets/images/icono_gro.png', 
                                        "Texto"     => 'Clients',
                                        "Submenu"   => ''
                                    ),
                                array( 
                                        "Href"      => base_url().'suc/',   
                                        "Icono"     => base_url().'assets/images/icupo.png', 
                                        "Texto"     => 'Suc',
                                        "Submenu"   => ''
                                    )
                            );
```

I am doing foreach loop like

```
foreach ($seccc  as $part)
    {
        foreach ($part as $item)
        {
            echo '<li>'.$item["Href"];
            if(is_array($item["Submenu"]))
            {
               foreach($item["Submenu"] as $subkey)
               {
                echo '<ul>';
                echo $subkey;                
                echo '</ul>';
               }                    
            }
        }
        echo '</li>';            
        }
    }
```

However I can not access to "Href", "Icono", "Texto" or "Submenu" items, How to access their values
seems `$item["Href"]` does not work

Comment: given the structure above, you are doing it correct. I would do a print_r of the array after building it to make sure the output is what you expect. Feel free to post that print_r output and someone can help if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($seccc as $part)
{
    // use $part instead of $item, here you can get $part['Icono'], $part['Texto'] etc
    echo '<li>'.$part["Href"]; 
    if(is_array($part["Submenu"])) 
    {
        // loop over $part['Submenu'] if it's an array
        foreach($part["Submenu"] as $key => $subkey)
        {
            echo '<ul>';
            echo $subkey;                
            echo '</ul>';
        }                    
    }
    echo '</li>';            
}
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting repeated correct display like
each part is being repeated 4 times...

Comment: @thecodeparadox You were using a useless loop I'm glad you updated it.

Comment: One last question, if I woul want to loop all items inside `$part["Submenu"] ` (in case it is an array) how should I do it?

Comment: @cMinor Already updated the answer how to loop over `$part['Submene']`.

Answer (score 1):

You have one loop to many

```
foreach ($seccc as $item)
{
  echo '<li>'.$item["Href"];
  if(is_array($item["Submenu"]))
  {
     foreach($item["Submenu"] as $subkey)
     {
      echo '<ul>';
      echo $subkey;                
      echo '</ul>';
     }                    
  }    
}
```